# Custom CSS class with Tailwind variants

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I noticed from one website the presence of a class `bordershadow`. Now this class is not listed in the Tailwind classes.

One unique thing about this class is that, it can have various variants and it seems to accept a color class. E.g. `bordershadow-red-500`. The color variable seems to change a certain color.

So, as an example, say we have `bordershadow-red-500`, the CSS definition for that is:

```css
.bordershadow-red-500 {
    box-shadow: var(--colors-custom-1) 0 0 0 0, var(--colors-custom-1) 0 0 0 0,
      var(--colors-custom-8) 0 1px 1px 0, RED_500_COLOR_INSERTED_HERE 0 0 0 1px, var(--colors-custom-1) 0 0 0 0,
      var(--colors-custom-1) 0 0 0 0, rgb(64 68 82/8%) 0 2px 5px 0;
  }
```

It can accept variants like hover:bordershadow-green-500

What is the name of this and how do you define a class like this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to achieve that.

1. use tailwind shadow-{color} property:
   https://play.tailwindcss.com/LM3zcjX0pb
2. if you need to set custom shadows, extend your theme. and will still work with shadow color utility.
   https://play.tailwindcss.com/Z9B9USNE0B?file=config

If this is not what you are looking please improve your question with a working example.